# "Optimal" local limit theorems for densities vanishing at zero

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limit-theorems

Consider a nonnegative stable distribution with a density that vanishes at zero, such as
$$f(t)=\frac{e^{-1/2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}},\qquad t\geq0.$$

Suppose (for simplicity) that we have i.i.d copies $(X_k)$ of a random variable supported on the maximal lattice $\mathbb Z$ in the domain of attraction of $f$, so that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P[\frac1{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\in dt]=\frac{e^{-1/2t}}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}}dt$$
for some norming sequence $a_n$. Then, the local limit theorem states that
$$\mathbb P[S_n=x]=a_n^{1/2}\frac{e^{-a_n/2x}}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}+\frac{o(1)}{a_n}\tag{1}$$
as $n\to\infty$, where $o(1)$ is uniform in $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Because $f$ vanishes at zero, we note that $(1)$ does not necessarily identify the leading order contribution to $\mathbb P[S_n=x]$ if $x=o(a_n)$, since
$$a_n^{1/2}\frac{e^{-a_n/2x}}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}=o(a_n^{-1})$$
in that case.

> **Question.** Does there exist general local limit theorems for such $f$ that correctly identify the leading order contribution to $\mathbb P[S_n=x]$ for $x=o(a_n^{-1})$, such as
>   $$\mathbb P[S_n=x]=a_n^{1/2}\frac{e^{-a_n/2x}}{\sqrt{2\pi x^3}}+o(1)\frac{a_n}{x^{3/2}}$$
>   with $o(1)$ uniform in some range of $x$ that includes $x=o(a_n)$?